# Virtualize Ubuntu server 12.0.4 into 3 different containers

Tags: server, virtualization

I have a dedicated server with 2 TB disk space, 16 GB memory. I need to virtualize it to 3 different containers (Public, private and DEV). I have been evaluating [Open VZ](http://openvz.org/Main_Page)

But it caused disk quota problems.

I appreciate some recommendations that allows me to virtualize the server and use the same kernel.

Comment: possible duplicate of [LXC Containers & Bridge Connection](http://askubuntu.com/questions/93942/lxc-containers-bridge-connection)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [LXC Web Panel](http://lxc-webpanel.github.io/install.html)

```
  sudo apt-get install lxc debootstrap bridge-utils -y
  sudo su
  wget http://lxc-webpanel.github.com/tools/install.sh -O - | bash
```

### Overview

[image]

## Containers Overview

[image]

## Manage Containers

[image]

### LXC Settings

[image]

### Manage Users

[image]

If you want command line take a look at [LXC Containers & Bridge Connection](https://askubuntu.com/questions/93942/lxc-containers-bridge-connection)

Comment: Thank you so much. I am trying this out now. Looks very promising and exactly what I needed.

Comment: Thank you once again. I have a follow up question: Where can I create websites folders such as /var/www or /home/xxxx in the new container. I have LAMP installed in the main kernel, do I still need to install LAMP in the created container ?

Comment: how can I access the new container via SSH ?

Comment: sudo lxc-console -n name-of-container -t 1 , default userid/password is ubuntu

Comment: Thank you so much. I couldn't login with user and password ubuntu/ubuntu !!

Comment: delete the comments please